# Java code displaying error on for loop

Tags: java

What's the problem in this Java code,there is a constant red line under the `for` loop, the code does work in a Java class but not in this one:

```
<%!
          EntityManagerFactory emf = javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Dima_TestPU");
        RegionJpaController djc = new RegionJpaController(emf); 
        List<Region> lstRegion = djc.findRegionEntities(); 
        for( Region device : lstRegion ) {
            System.out.println(device.getId());
            System.out.println(device.getName());
            System.out.println(device.getLatitude());
        }
%>
```

Comment: java is not javascript

Comment: You should start with the basics...Java is not Javascript....

Answer (score 0):

It's because JavaScript has nothing to do with Java. You are messing around with syntax of different languages.

In JavaScript for loop looks like this:

```
for (var i in myArray) {
    console.log(myArray[i]);
}
```

or

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(myArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: `for...in` statement could be used, but for iterating arrays `for-in` should be avoided, that statement is meant to enumerate object properties

src: [loop-through-an-array-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript#answer-3010848)

Comment: I am using JSP and it says online that you can add Java code in a Java server Page